# MySQL REGEXP to select digits

Tags: mysql, regex

```
SELECT 'Some more(user) found = 50' REGEXP '\d+' as T;
```

results:

```
+---+
| T |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I am expecting

```
50
```

What is the correct REGEXP to select one or more digits?

Comment: First, `\d` is not supported in MySQL REGEXP. Second, you cannot use REGEXP to fetch parts of entries, it only checks if an entry contains some pattern.

Comment: If you can show us more data, maybe there is some other workaround.

Comment: I have text like the one shown in example. I was wondering if there is a way to extract the digits out of the text and treat them like numbers.

Comment: Yes, this may be possible, but not using regex extraction, at least not in MySQL.  Will the numbers always be occurring after an equals sign?

Answer (score 0):

You need a function for that:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS STRIP_NON_DIGIT;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION STRIP_NON_DIGIT(input VARCHAR(255))
   RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
BEGIN
   DECLARE output   VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
   DECLARE iterator INT          DEFAULT 1;
   WHILE iterator < (LENGTH(input) + 1) DO
      IF SUBSTRING(input, iterator, 1) IN ( '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' ) THEN
         SET output = CONCAT(output, SUBSTRING(input, iterator, 1));
      END IF;
      SET iterator = iterator + 1;
   END WHILE;
   RETURN output;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;

mysql> SELECT STRIP_NON_DIGIT('Some more(user) found = 50') AS n;
+------+
| n    |
+------+
| 50   |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's regexp does not include most backslash shortcuts.

Instead of `\d`, use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]`.